# OrderedDict vs Dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

In [Tim Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951209/1860929) to "Are there any reasons not to use an ordered dictionary", he says

> OrderedDict is a subclass of dict.
>
> It's not a lot slower, but at least doubles the memory over using a plain dict.

Now, while going through a [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25054003/1860929), I tried some sample checks using `ipython` and both of them contradict the earlier reasoning:

1. both `dict` and `OrderedDict` are of same size
2. operating on an `OrderedDict` takes easily around 7-8 times more time than operating on a `dict` (Hence a lot slower)

Can someone explain to me where I'm going wrong in my reasoning?

---

#### Create a large Dict and OrderedDict and compare sizes:

```
import sys
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

test_dict = {}
test_ordered_dict = OrderedDict()

for key in range(10000):
    test_dict[key] = random.random()
    test_ordered_dict[key] = random.random()

sys.getsizeof(test_dict)
786712

sys.getsizeof(test_ordered_dict)
786712
```

#### Check time taken for the insertions using `%timeit`:

```
import sys
import random
from collections import OrderedDict

def operate_on_dict(r):
    test_dict = {}
    for key in range(r):
        test_dict[key] = random.random()

def operate_on_ordered_dict(r):
    test_ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
    for key in range(r):
        test_ordered_dict[key] = random.random()

%timeit for x in range(100): operate_on_ordered_dict(100)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.24 ms per loop

%timeit for x in range(100): operate_on_dict(100)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.23 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem with size is due to the fact that there's no `__sizeof__` method defined in Python 2.X [implementation of `OrderedDict`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l26), so it simply falls back to dict's `__sizeof__` method.

To prove this here I've created a class `A` here which extends `list` and also added an additional method `foo` to check if that affects the size.

```
class A(list):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return list.__getitem__(self, k)
    def foo(self):
        print 'abcde'

>>> a = A(range(1000))
>>> b = list(range(1000))
```

But still same size is returned by `sys.getsizeof`:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(a), sys.getsizeof(b)
(9120, 9120)
```

Of course `A` is going to be slow because its methods are running in Python while list's method will run in pure C.

```
>>> %%timeit
... for _ in xrange(1000):
...     a[_]
... 
1000 loops, best of 3: 449 µs per loop
>>> %%timeit
for _ in xrange(1000):
    b[_]
... 
10000 loops, best of 3: 52 µs per loop
```

And this seems to be fixed in Python 3 where there's a well defined [`__sizeof__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L174) method now:

```
def __sizeof__(self):
    sizeof = _sys.getsizeof
    n = len(self) + 1                       # number of links including root
    size = sizeof(self.__dict__)            # instance dictionary
    size += sizeof(self.__map) * 2          # internal dict and inherited dict
    size += sizeof(self.__hardroot) * n     # link objects
    size += sizeof(self.__root) * n         # proxy objects
    return size
```

Comment: +1 I think you are right about the missing `__sizeof__`, but your answer doesn't explain Tim's claim that `It's not a *lot* slower`. FWIW, I get the same 7-8x factor of running time whether I choose a range of 100 or 10000 keys.

Comment: @mu無 May be that's what Tim meant by **lot** there.

Comment: @mu無 Better post a comment on his answer.

Comment: [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18951143/are-there-any-reasons-not-to-use-an-ordered-dictionary/18951209#comment38985313_18951209)

Comment: > also added an additional method foo to check if that affects the size.


Adding method does not increase size of instance, as methods are attributes on the class. A more accurate explanation would be by adding a new attribute "foo" in the subclass's `__init__`