# Ordered dictionary of ordered dictionaries need to be converted to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, ordereddictionary

I have a dataset which might have n level of ordered dictionary of ordered dictionaries,Now i need to convert all of them into normal dictionaries,Is there a easier method to do other than recursive search and conversion.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
an=OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])

aw=OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', OrderedDict([('1.225','777')]))])

print dict(an)
print dict(aw)
{'data': '1.225', 'method': 'constant'}
{'data': OrderedDict([('1.225', '777')]), 'method': 'constant'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not. You can wrap your recursive algorithm in a function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def ordered_to_regular_dict(d):
    if isinstance(d, OrderedDict):
        d = {k: ordered_to_regular_dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    return d

aw = OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', OrderedDict([('1.225','777')]))])
res = ordered_to_regular_dict(aw)

# {'data': {'1.225': '777'}, 'method': 'constant'}
```

Comment: dang you beat me once again, guess i'll delete :p

Comment: A more general solution is to use `copy.deepcopy()`, after customizing the way that `OrderedDict` is copied: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225078/162094