# Memory leak free OrderedDict alternative in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, ordereddict

We are checking whether one of our packages leaves garbage objects in the Python gc and found that `collections.OrderedDict` objects are not deleted by the ref-count mechanism but are put into the GC, with the following references (when pprint'ing them and tweaking the output a little):

```
<type 'list'> object at 0x10a876ab8:
[ <Recursive reference to list object at 0x10a876ab8>,
  <Recursive reference to list object at 0x10a876ab8>,
  None]
```

This seems to be the same issue as the one reported in https://bugs.python.org/issue9825. That issue was fixed in Python 3.2, and indeed, the reference cycle shown above appears on Python 2.7 but not on Python 3.7.

Is there a ref-cycle free alternative to `collections.OrderedDict` for Python 2.7?

**Update:**

1. I found that `ordereddict.OrderedDict` also has the same reference cycle.
2. I am fully aware that Python 2.7 is out of support. Nevertheless, we still need to support our package on Python 2.7.
3. The answer of @Ramsha Siddiqui points to the SortedDict of Django. I verified that in Django 1.7, its SortedDict does not have reference cycles. However, SortedDict was removed from Django (at least in its version 1.11).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python ordered garbage collectible dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667057/python-ordered-garbage-collectible-dictionary)

Answer (score -1):

You can use sorted() on any dictionary's items like so:

```
odt = dict(sorted(dt.items()))
```

> UPDATE: Preserving Original Order

If you want to preserve original order, there is a Django libary for that too:

```
from django.utils.datastructures import SortedDict
d2 = SortedDict()
```

Let me know if this helps your case.

> UPDATE: [Duplicate] Reference: [Python ordered garbage collectible dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667057/python-ordered-garbage-collectible-dictionary)

```
del collections.OrderedDict.__del__
```

This seems to be the solution for gaining the ability to use OrderedDicts in a reference cycle. You will lose having the OrderedDict free all its resources immediately upon deletion.

Comment: Sorting the items is not the same as preserving their original order, which is what OrderedDict does.

Comment: thats true - I didnt think of that before. I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to use the django SortedDict, but it was no longer in the django version I installed (1.11). From https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SortedDict: "SortedDict is deprecated as of Django 1.7 and will be removed in Django 1.9. Use ​collections.OrderedDict instead". Thanks for the help, anyway!

Comment: Oh and just for the record: The SortedDict from Django 1.7 has no reference cycles according to our garbage object check!!